# Modifying the Python range function

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying two variants of the python range function with the primary objective of making the function inclusive. However neither seems to be working

```
def main():
    for i in standard_range(1, 25, 1):
        print(i, end='')


def inclusive_range(*args):
    numargs = len(args)
    if numargs < 1:
        raise TypeError("Requires atleast one argument")
    elif numargs == 1:
        stop = args[0]
        start = 0
        step = 1
    elif numargs == 2:
        (start, stop) = args
        step = 1
    elif numargs == 3:
        (start, stop, step) = args
    else:
        raise TypeError("Cannot have more than three arguments")

    i = start
    while i <= stop:
        yield i
        i += step


def standard_range(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i <= stop:
        yield i
        i += step


if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    main()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are they not working?  Provide expected output vs. current output.

Comment: It works for me. Which is the problem? Maybe the problem is defining main function before standard_range

Comment: No, the problem isn't the main() function's position. Since it isn't called until the other functions have been defined it won't cause any errors. But I agree it's confusing that the poster doesn't give expected _vs._ actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your exact code, `main()` won't run because you have spaces before and after `__main__`:

```
if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    main()
```

Remove the spaces:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`standard_range` should not print the stop value, so use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
while i < stop:
```

If I make those changes, and use this main:

```
def main():
    print(*standard_range(1,25,1))
    print(*inclusive_range(1,25,1))
```

The result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: Worked for me, the space thing. Thanks.